# Send json as value through jquery ajax and javax.ws web service failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I got the problem with sending json as a value through jquery ajax and javax.ws as my web service.
So this is my ajax script

```
var _data = JSON.stringify(xdata.children[prop]);

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('_data', _data);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/ribwebservice/rest/service/save',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    data: {'json' : _data}
}).done(function(data){

    alert('Page Saved');

});
```

And this is my web service code

```
@Path("/service")
```

public class RibWebService {

```
@POST
@Path("save")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain", "text/html"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/plain", "text/html"})
public Response savePage(@QueryParam("json") String json){
    String output = "success";

    PageSave page = new PageSave();
    page.savePage(json);

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}

@POST
@Path("load")
public Response loadPage(){
    PageLoad page   = new PageLoad();
    String output   = page.getRibPageJsonList();

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
}
```

I have try to change my data key from 'json' to json, and vice versa, there still left me with this error.
500 (Internal Server Error)

But when I call my web service through postman with these configuration :
type : POST
url params => key : json, value = my_ajax_code
Content-Type : text/html (and have tried to set text/plain too)

My REST service works fine without leaving 500 error code.

So what was actually happened in here?

Answer (score 1):

Update after your feedback:

You issue is on the server side.

Unfortunately, I haven't got knowledge of the language used there, but I from what I can see you are expecting a string named json ( and until here everything is correct).

The main problem is that your json object is strigify so it cannot be used until you parse it.

When it reach your server side, the code is not accessible as a json object, but its a normal string. Usually this kind of problem can be solved by testing one part at the time

1) Debug the request that get sent to the server with the debugger;
2) Send an hardcoded string ( just in case there is some special character in the _data object)
3) Server side, take everything out and just return the data itself and see that the success callback is triggered successfully on the client side.

By taking this steps you will understand where the actual problem lies.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I think that was incorrect. I have "json" as my query parameter in my web service, it usually called from url like json='my_value_to_server'. I've wraped the _data with json as my key like this :
var dataPacket = {json : _data}
then I turn dataPacket into json string with JSON.stringify(dataPacket) and put them into data : => 
data : JSON.stringify(dataPacket). 
And I also try to send _data directly like you have wrote.
So what the real problem is?

Comment: I haven't got knowledge of your service side code, but I can assume that the stringify json object need to be decoded before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the @QueryParam incorrectly. As I understand it this annotation returns URL parameters(More information on this annotation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/)).

So right now your service would get the JSON from the URL parameter JSON(The posted data would be lost).

```
/service?json={JSON object}
```